# can't build default blazor project in 0.5.1

Tags: blazor

I can't seem to build the default blazor project in 0.5.1 and get the following error:

> Error MSB3073 The command "dotnet
>   "C:\Users\R.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.blazor.build\0.5.1\targets../tools/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Build.dll"
>   write-boot-json obj\Debug\netstandard2.0\WebApplication6.dll
>   --references "C:\Users\R\Source\Repos\WebApplication6\WebApplication6\obj\Debug\netstandard2.0\blazor/bootjson-references.txt"
>   --embedded-resources "C:\Users\R\Source\Repos\WebApplication6\WebApplication6\obj\Debug\netstandard2.0\blazor/embedded.resources.txt"
>   --linker-enabled --output "C:\Users\R\Source\Repos\WebApplication6\WebApplication6\obj\Debug\netstandard2.0\blazor/blazor.boot.json""
>   exited with code -2147450730. WebApplication6
>   C:\Users\R.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.blazor.build\0.5.1\targets\Blazor.MonoRuntime.targets
>   635

Comment: What does `dotnet --version` in your app path say?

Answer (score 1):

change SDK version to what you installed on your machine in `global.json` or try to delete `global.json`

If you want to know which version of .net core installed, run following command:

```
dotnet --version
```

Answer (score 0):

I have got the same error. It was because i had installed .net core 2.1 preview sdk. After I downloaded the none-preview it worked fine.

You can download it over thins link:
https://blazor.net/docs/get-started.html

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was caused by spaces in the Project Name (or somewhere in the folder structure). I completely removed spaces (and replaced some with underscores _) and that did the trick for me.